# Regex -> detect a pattern -> move it to the start of the line

Tags: regex, file, sed

It is the first time that I use this platform because it is impossible for me to find the solution.

I have this html code:

```
<img ...></img><a ...><span ...
```

I need this:

```
<a ...><img ...></img><span ...
```

Where `...` would be the content of the pattern (like `<img.*.</img>`) because it will be done in a bulk way and the information changes. The file has this format:

```
<img ...></img><a ...><span ...
.....
<img ...></img><a ...><span ...
.....
<img ...></img><a ...><span ...
.....
<img ...></img><a ...><span ...
```

As you can guess, I need to put the `<img>` tag inside the `<a>` tag. I tried to take the pattern `<a.*.>` and move it to the beginning of the line but I have not succeeded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You generally should not be using regex to manipulate HTML content, which might be nested and have other complexities.  However, assuming your `<img>` and `<a>` tags always be just one level, you could try the following find and replace, in Sed:

```
echo "<img ...></img><a ...><span ..." | sed 's/\(<img[^>]*><\/img>\)\(<a[^>]*>\)/\2\1/'
```

This prints:

```
<a ...><img ...></img><span ...
```

Here is a more general solution, also easier to read:

```
Find:    (<img[^>]*><\/img>)(<a[^>]*>)
Replace: $2$1
```

### Demo

This solution simply captures, in two separate groups `$1` and `$2`, the `<img>` and `<a>` tags.  Then, in the replacement, it swaps the two tags to give you the order you want.

Comment: Thank you. But how could I run it in sed?

Comment: You never tagged your question with Sed, and therefore I did not know the tool you were using.

Comment: Thank you. In the end I did it like this: sed -i -E "s/(<img.*)(<a .*.>)/\2\1/" file.txt

Answer (score 0):

In the end I solved it like this:

```
sed -i -E "s/(<img.*)(<a .*.>)/\2\1/" file.txt
```